# windows phone 8.1 DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147483638

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to run `windows phone 8.1 app` on my windows phone(version 10.0.10586). When I click on run button in **VS2015**. It gives me following error

> DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147483638

I have recently updated my VS2015 to update 3. After updating this it is giving me this issue. Can anyone faced same issue? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: try running the app on the emulators ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it but it is saying `flash.vdh` does not exists.

Comment: @AjayPunekar Have you fixed it ?

Comment: @OmarHassan yes. But it takes almost 2 days.

Comment: @AjayPunekar How you fixed it ?

Comment: @OmarHassan see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution after lot of trials. I spend almost 2 to 3 days.

Go to **control panel** -> **Programs and features** -> select **VS2015**

Click on change button. After clicking it take some time to configure some things. after that there are three options Modify/Repair/Uninstall. Click on modify and select **update 3** and other required update. After selection Click on **update** button. But before that make sure your internet connection is working and fast. Once it start update it take almost **5 to 6 hrs** to update. If all thing worked perfectly it will say **restart now** or if any failure occurred during installation it will give you the list of failed component. Then you have to again repeat this process.

All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

I also spent a long time trying to fix this. Tried everything without success until I did a "repair" through the VisualStudio installer.